# Does connecting any two points in a set result in a convex set?

Tags: convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

This might be silly, but I am not sure.

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R^2$. Suppose that for any two points $x,y \in A$, I "add" the straight segment $[x,y]$ between them. Is the result convex?

That is, is $\cup_{(x,y)\in A^2} [x,y]$
convex?

Comment: What if $A$ is simply the vertices of a triangle (e.g. $A = \{ (0,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$)?

Comment: Maybe if you do it twice. First step we get from some points to something like a "polygon". Second step we fill in the "polygon".

Comment: @Vepir. Interesting question. I was actually implicitly thinking on $A$ as a continuous path in the plane. I have now asked about this here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3674400/does-connecting-any-two-points-in-a-graph-result-in-a-convex-set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you take three non-collinear points then the union of the lines joining them  is the triangle with those points as vertices. This is not convex.

Comment: Thank you. I was implicitly thinking on $A$ as a continuous path in the plane. Since I forgot to mention this, I (of course) accepted your answer. Do you have an idea if the answer changes if we begin with a graph of a function? I asked about this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3674400/does-connecting-any-two-points-in-a-graph-result-in-a-convex-set