# Does connecting any two points in a graph result in a convex set?

Tags: convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

This is a [follow-up](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3674376/does-connecting-any-two-points-in-a-set-result-in-a-convex-set) question.

Let $F:[0,1] \to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function, and let $G=\{ (x,F(x))\,|\,  x \in [0,1] \}$ be the graph of $F$.

Is $\cup_{(x,y)\in G^2} [x,y]$
convex?

Comment: Do you mean $\cup_{(x,y) \in G} (x,y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  This by a 1929 result of Fenchel, referenced in a 2011 [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.5942.pdf) paper.  I have not read the Fenchel paper, but have looked at a more recent paper the arXiv one cites.

The older paper is

W. Fenchel, "Uber Krümmung und Windung geschlossener Raumkurven". *Math. Ann.*, 101 (1929), 238–252.

The more recent one is

Olof Hanner and Hans Rådström,
"A Generalization of a Theorem of Fenchel".
*Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society*
Vol. 2, No. 4 (Aug., 1951), pp. 589-593 (5 pages).

Each point in the convex hull of $G$ can be written as a convex combination of at most 3 extreme points of the convex hull, by Caratheodory. But because $G$ is connected it turns out, by Fenchel, that each point in the c.h. of $G$ is a convex combination of $\le2$ extreme points.  The extreme points of the closed convex hull of $G$ are contained in $G$, so if you believe Fenchel, your statement follows.

See also this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77379/convex-hull-of-path-connected-sets) with other references.

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting answer. BTW, how do you prove that  the extreme points of the closed convex hull of $G$ are contained in $G$? It seems to me that this is just a reformulation of Fenchel's theorem  in this case. Do you imply that this could be established independently?

Comment: @AsafShachar This is elementary, but the proof depends on the precise way things are defined.  See Corollary 18.3.1 in Rockafellar's book, or pp I-333 and II-96 of Choquet's _Lectures on Analysis_.  A point $p\in H$ is extreme in convex $H$ if $H\setminus\{p\}$ is convex; the convex hull $H$ of $G$ is the intersection of all convex sets containing $G$.  If $p\notin G$ you have a contradiction: $H\subseteq H\setminus\{p\}$ fails.